how can I update a variable in an object of vectors
I want to update an object's variables within a vector array of objects, using input from the user as to what variable they wish to update.
the code is:
class Employee {
public:
    std::string empID, empName, empTitle, empHireDate, empSalary;
    Employee() {}
    // constructor
    Employee(string id, string name, string title, string hireDate, string salary) :
        empID(id),
        empName(name),
        empTitle(title),
        empHireDate(hireDate),
        empSalary(salary)
    {}

    //returns the employee's ID
    string getEmpID() {
        return empID;
    }
};

(Operator== function, if you saw this project before, you know.)

class employeeMutator : public Employee 
    void updateEmployee(string input) {
        //requests what the user wants to update, and updates it
        if (input == "1") {
            cout << "what is the new name? ";
            string name;
            cin >> name;
            empName = name;
            cout << "updated.";
            cout << "\n";
        }
        (...) repeat and change for other variables. Yes, yes, there is almost certainly a cleaner way to do
        this.
        }
    }
};

int Main() {
    vector <Employee> Payroll;
    Employee employee;

    (insert a few test employees here, they all have different IDs)

    string mutate;
    cout << "what would you like to update? '1' to update the name, '2' to update the title, '3' to update
    the hire date, and '4' to update the salary: ";
    cin >> mutate;

    //looks for what the user wants to update
    for (Employee employee : Payroll) {
        if (input == employee.getEmpID()) {
            employeeMutator update;
            update.updateEmployee(mutate);
        }
    }
};


The code compiles and runs, but when I use a display method, it shows the vector was never updated.
I've been looking at other similar posts on this and other websites, which haven't helped, and they have been noting a possible copying of the vector. What's is going on here exactly to cause the update to fail, and how can I fix it?

Can you please turn this into a [mcve], with real code in place of your pseudocode comments, so that someone could actually compile and test it?

With employeeMutator update; you create a brand new and independent object, which is unrelated to the employee object. Any changes you make to the update object is done only to that object, the employee object will be unaffected.

And in the loop you create copies of the objects in the vector. Modifying a copy will not modify the original. Together with the employeeMutator problem, it seems you have skipped or missing some of the basics of C++ and how objects and inheritance work.

If you want to be able to quickly find what Employee to update. Replace std::vector<Employee> with std::unordered_map<std::string,Employee> and use EmpID as key.

@PepijnKramer How is an std::map lookup with an std::string key faster than member access?

@bitmask II was referring to Payroll (which is now a vector).

Your mutator should not be an employee. Think about it from a grammatical perspective. The thing that has the job of changing an record of type X is not an X. Frankly, your update doesn't need to a class member to begin with. A free function will do. Or a friend of Employee.
Furthermore, you probably want to iterate over the employees by reference, not by value. Because otherwise you would change a temporary copy.
And lastly, prefixing member names with "emp" to indicate that they belong to Employee is redundant: They already are members of that class.
void updateEmployee(Employee& employee, std::string const& input) {
  //requests what the user wants to update, and updates it
  if (input == "1") {
    std::cout << "what is the new name? " << std::flush;
    std::cin >> employee.name;
  } else if (input == "2") {
    // ...
  }
  std::cout << "updated." << std::endl;
}

...
  for (Employee& employee : payroll) {
    if (input == employee.getEmpID()) {
      updateEmployee(employee,mutate);
    }
  }


first point: its a consequence of me not really understanding what the professor was asking for the assignment in question. its within the topic on Inheritance, and all he wanted was an employee class, with the above variables, I assumed the Prof. wanted an assignment showcasing inheritance, but it shows nothing of the sort on reading it again (whoops.), somewhat an answer to @Some programmer dude was talking about in the upper comment area.


fixing that, thanks


just a habit i have, I'll try to fix that.



Just made those changes, and it still did not fix the problem.

@DanielGowin You need to show your new code, to get help with that. Ask a new question if you like.

@DanielGowin The way I would to it would be to write some setter methods on Employee, setName, setTitle etc and just use those. That's the simple solution.
